# Does Spring Statemachine support Java 17 or above?

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

Does Spring Statemachine support Java 17 or above?

Their documentation says that the supported version is Java 8. However, the library dependency does seem to compile in a Java 17 environment.

I am new to this library and haven't used a lot of its features.

Therefore I may be wrong. Would you mind sharing your experience here?

Comment: Java tends to be backwards compatible. A library built for Java N will also run on Java N+1. The only real major caveats in recent years were the module system (introduced in Java 9) and the related restriction of reflection access to system classes. But those only hit some kinds of libraries (the ones that did some shady stuff internally, mostly). For the majority of libraries those are non-issues. So if it seems to work, it'll probably work just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. I have recently written a library using JDK8. I wasn't able use the same library in JDK17 workspace due to compilation errors. It wasn't specific to a feature that was deprecated in JDK17. Just the compatibility issue at byte code level. It would be nice to hear from the users of Spring State machine about their experiences in upgrading their JDK version whilst using this library. My concerns are around whether this library is actively maintained and has good community support. What I want to avoid is to use a library which is not actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we are using java 17 with SSM 3.x. In other words, yes